# ERROR:UNABLE TO START DAEMON PROCESS -- Gradle build in Android Studio 1.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
```

This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.

**For example,**

An unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at **http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html**

Please read the following process output to find out more:

`13:41:17.232 [main] DEBUG o.g.l.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonMain - Assuming the daemon was started with following jvm opts: [-XX:MaxPermSize=256m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xmx1024m, -Dfile.encoding=x-windows-949, -Duser.country=KR, -Duser.language=ko, -Duser.variant]`

This error occurs while Building or Making new project.